# Babel es6 dynamic require error + react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Right now I use this code to route in my app and load components dynamically, but I get errors about 'fs, net' etc.. I tried dirty hacks in `webpack.config.js` like `{fs:"empty"}`. But it doesn't fix the issue...

Here's the code:

```
function getData(path) { 
return( 
 (location, callback) => (
    require.ensure([], require => 
    callback(null, require(path).default)))
 )
 }


    export default (

    <Route path="/" getComponent={ getData('./containers/App') }>

            ....children 

            </Route>
     )
```

However everything works fine with no errors if I put the function inside the `Route`

```
export default (

<Route path="/" getComponent={ (location, callback) => (
require.ensure([], require => 
callback(null, require('./containers/App').default)))}>

        ....children 

        </Route>
 )
```

I think the issue is that export conflicts with `getData`. Any help's good :)